# Axios gets different X-CSRF token then Postman

Tags: javascript, get, axios, postman, token

Why is the x-csrf token which I get from my axios request different then the one I get from postman? This is how I get it

```
headers: {
  "X-CSRF-Token": "FETCH"
}
```

Also I cannot use the x-csrf token from my axios request in Postman, it gets denied with the error message that it is not a valid x-csrf token

Also the token from axios is different everytime I do a GET request. The token from Postman stays the same for arround like 10-15minutes.

Token from Postman: t7HbFUE0sgE4vM36BN_u_Q==

Token from Axios: 16c47S-pA5oxZu6t_pUi8Q==

Comment: can you please show both tokens recieved, i have a guess but i need to see both token to be 100% sure and not give you a wrong answer

Comment: I editet the original post with both tokens

Comment: are using the same header in both requests ?

Comment: Yes the header used in my axios get request is actually copied from postman

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the x-csrf token which I get from my axios request different then the one I get from postman?

A CSRF defence would be useless if an attacker could predict the token that would be given to the browser being used for the attack.

A unique CSRF token is generated for each … something (often browser session, sometimes page load, sometimes something in between) and associated with a specific client with (usually) a session/cookie.

[Portswigger has a good overview of CSRF](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf)

Comment: oh i see, and because i run my code with node.js and litereally have nothing else then the get request in my whole code I get a different token everytime because I'm not saving anything with cookies etc

Comment: @JangoCG — Correct.